# Composer update connection timed out

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

The composer update is not working . Occur bellow error.

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "http://packagist.org/p/provider-2014%24b3998ac22974d61da8558875767e72b
  620b5be13d2d6da5405badc66b8a65b54.json" file could not be downloaded: faile
  d to open stream: Connection timed out